# Who do I have to deliver the pumpkin soup to?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

After I knocked the chandelier down in the *Lumpy Pumpkin*, the owner strong-armed me into delivering hot pumpkin soup to someone in Skyloft, I believe a knight of some kind.  Unfortunately, I didn't write down his name or title.  I wasn't able to find him before the soup went cold.  When I went back to the *Lumpy Pumpkin*, the owner didn't mention anything about his request.  I went to knock the chandelier down again, but it was gone.

What's the name of the individual I'm supposed to deliver it to?  Is it too late to make the delivery?

Comment: +1 I had trouble with this too. I got lucky and guessed who it was. You might want to try to deliver, or drink, the first dose of soup before talking to the owner again.

Comment: I accidentally drank the soup and had to go back to get more soup and the owner charged me ten rupees for it... You should try that.

Comment: Well you _can_ buy them normally there and drink it.  You just get it free the first time for this quest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Knight Commander Eagus is the recipient of the soup. He is the one who trains you with the sword at the start of the game, and is located at the knight academy, inside the sparring hall.

Here is a picture of him ([image source](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda14-skyward-sword-characters.php)):

[image]

Here's a video showing the outside of the sparring hall if you cannot recall what it looks like, or where it is:

Comment: Can you still get pumpkin soup even though you knocked the chandelier down?

Comment: @KezamiFlame123 Yes you can.

Answer (score 4):

It's the Knight Commander, the man in the Sparring Hall that you got the sword from. If you failed to deliver it to him in time, try giving it to him anyway or see if you can buy a bottle.

Knight Commander Eagus:
[image: Knight Commander Eagus's picture]

[The image is from his page at IGN.](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/Knight_Commander_Eagus)

Answer (score 3):

You are supposed to deliver it to Commander Eagus, in the Sparring Hall (where you got your sword from, and were taught how to use it).

However, there is a 5 minute time limit after which the Pumpkin Soup will go cold, which you have likely exceeded at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Knight Commander Eagus is who you deliver the soup to. He is the man you got the training sword from to go rescue your Crimson Loftwing.